# Sum all the values of a plot in R

Tags: r

I have this plot:

```
pts1 <- seq(-1,4, 0.005)
plot1 <- plot(pts1,dnorm(pts1),type="l", xlim=c(-4,4),xlab="",ylab="Densidad")
```

I want to sum all the values that the x-axis values take in the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean CDF?

```
plot(pts1, pnorm(pts1), type = "l", xlim = c(-4, 4), xlab = "", ylab = "Densidad")
```

or

```
plot(pts1, cumsum(dnorm(pts1)) * 0.005, type = "l", xlim = c(-4, 4), xlab = "", ylab = "Densidad")
```

[image]

---

**Update**

```
> pnorm(-1:4,lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 8.413447e-01 5.000000e-01 1.586553e-01 2.275013e-02 1.349898e-03
[6] 3.167124e-05
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, what I mean is how can I get the numerical value of the sum of the corresponding y values to my x values. I mean, what is the result of P(X > -2 ) ? To get that value I need to sum  P(X=-1) + P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2) + P(X=3) + P(X=4), summing that visually is a bit hard so I was wondering if there was a function to tell you the value that an x value takes in the y axis and them sum them all, or maybe sum them all directly. Sorry if I wasn't clear at first

Comment: @helpme see my update. I guess you may need `pnorm`